# What does includePaths.library in application.ini do?

Tags: php, zend-framework, include-path

I'm using

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/library',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

in the index.php file, so what does `includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"` do? I'd like to remove one of them and I'd prefer keep the line in application.ini, but I'd like to know what do I have to do in order to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both do the same thing. The problem with removing the one in your index.php file is that the require_once 'Zend/Application.php' call you presumably have later in that file will then fail (unless ZF is on your standard include path). So, I'd suggest removing the application.ini one, which shouldn't have any ill effects.